# Mangle words to bytearray of lo/hibytes

Tags: python-3.x, array, integer, byte

I would like to refactor the following code snippet adapted from a project I'm involved. It is part of a code to control power outlets via network. The code snippet was written by myself based on the original code for demonstration and review related purposes. E.g. the original code was part of a class containing the `self` parameter, it only took two words and the words were part of a challenge response from the power outlet.
Latter is given as background information, only.

```
def mangle_lo_hi_bytes(word1, word2, word3, word4):
    answer = [
        word1 & 0xFF,
        word1 >> 8 & 0xFF,
        word2 & 0xFF,
        word2 >> 8 & 0xFF,
        word3 & 0xFF,
        word3 >> 8 & 0xFF,
        word4 & 0xFF,
        word4 >> 8 & 0xFF,
    ]
    return bytes(answer)
```

->

```
2211443366558877
```

Please review the code in terms of

- DRY paradigm
- Performance
- Reusability
- Compactness
- Resource usage

Examples:

- The code extracts each lo/hibyte of each word in extra statements. It does not use looping or list comprehension. Therefore it is repetitive.
- The code does everything manually and does not make use of pythons built in functionalities. This may affect, e.g. performance.
- The code relies on the endianness of the host machine. This may result in difficult traceable bugs.
- The code first sets up a list and then converts this list into bytes. This eats up additional memory.

What I tried:

- Use a list comprehension to make the code more compact -> I ran into the issue that I could not nest a list comprehension of a list into another list comprehension like so: `answer = [byte for byte in [lo(word), hi(word)] for word in [word1, word2, word3, word4]]`
- Trying to apply `num.to_bytes(2, byteorder="little")`. Here is my code: `b"".join([num.to_bytes(2, byteorder="little") for num in nums])` where nums would be a list of word1...word4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote essentially

```
def mangle_lo_hi_bytes(word1: int, word2: int, word3: int, word4: int):
```

It likely would be more convenient for the caller if it accepts a vector of words:

```
def mangle_lo_hi_bytes(words: Iterable[int]):
```

In any event, the signature should absolutely be accompanied
by a """docstring""" that explains how expected input
will be mapped to output, including some mention of endianess.

---

You complain that per-word nesting is inconvenient
to process: `[(lo1, hi1), (lo2, hi2), ...]`.
The standard library offers
[chain.from_iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes)
to flatten such an iterable.

---

On to the meat of it.

Your shifting / masking approach seems to be a straightforward
translation of some C code, perhaps even an unrolled loop.
You point out it has several shortcomings.

An easy way to DRY it up would be to generate byte pairs:

```
def gen_lo_hi(word: int):
    yield word & 0xFF
    yield word1 >> 8 & 0xFF

words = (word1, word2, word3, word4)

result = bytes(map(gen_lo_hi, words))
```

You mentioned a performance concern,
which motivates avoiding the slight generator overhead.

The most natural way to address your serialization use case
is to simply use
[pack](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.pack)
from the standard library.
It was designed for precisely what you're trying to do.

For 16-bit words your format string should be `"HHHH"`
plus the appropriate
[byte order](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-strings).

---

This code achieves only a subset of its goals.

Prior to merging down to `main`,
it should be replaced by the standard `pack(...)` approach.

Comment: The `struct.pack` refactoring works perfectly and it is much clearer than my hack `b"".join([num.to_bytes(2, byteorder="little") for num in nums])`